# iPhone SDK windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, sdk

Is there an official iPhone SDK for Windows?
I thought there was none, but a colleague at work said he downloaded one from Apple.


Which one of us is wrong? I thought Apple doesn't release it's developer tools for windows.
Or is that just Windows on non-apple computers ?

Comment: well i wish there were.. truly :-)

Comment: Thsi is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows, among others.

Comment: DragonFireSDK is an official SDK for Windows.  It uses C/C++ code to create the apps and there is no need for a Mac computer.  Check out their site for more info: www.dragonfiresdk.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no official SDKs for iPhone that runs on Windows. The [official SDK is here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/) and is only for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

John, my son, if you have a hackintosh which means a Mac OS X installed on a Intel architecture you can have the Xcode. Sorry but its true! You would have installed on a VM or installed directly on your desktop. The bad news is that you need to fool the Mac OS to bypass somekind of request authorization it may require.

Please read the followign url and be more smarter than a 2min ago.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86

For those whom want to code for iPhone on windows enviromnent please follow the white rabbit here:
http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available/

Cheers and regards!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that the official SDK can only run on a Mac.  However there is a development kit that runs on Windows, the DragonFireSDK.  It allows you to develop and test on a Window computer and then submit the code to a Mac build computer operated by the folks who sold and support the DragonFireSDK.  The output from the build can then be loaded back onto the windows machine, imported into iTunes and then loaded into your iDevice.  NO HACKS!

Answer (score -1):

Probably the only way to do that is to make yourself a hackintosh.

Comment: That still doesn't the SDK available on Windows.

Comment: Well a hackintosh is a windows that runs mac osx

Comment: No, Windows is an OS, not a computer. Thus, this does not make the SDK available to run on Windows. It makes the SDK available to run on an Intel-based PC which has been hacked into running the Mac OS X operating system.

Comment: I was trying to dumb it down. Google hackintosh if you don't know what  you are talking about. Because it seems you really don't.

Comment: I've had a hackintosh, as well as my current Mac. I know exactly what you're talking about. It still does not get the SDK running under Windows, which is what the OP requested.