# iPhone Application Development on Windows

Tags: iphone, c++, windows, sdk

As I've seen many questions related to this topic but this is a completely different question. I wanted to ask if there is any header file or anything else which will help me to program iPhone Application on Windows using Visual C++ 2008 and then test it on my phone (and not really make it open to the real market) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK windows ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086871/iphone-sdk-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to develop native iphone applications on Windows. OS X is required to develop iOS applications.

There are third party tools, such as Corona, and Monotouch, which will allow you to write you application in languages other than objective-C, but in order to test in the simulator or on a physical device, you again need OS X, and the iOS SDK, which require Apple hardware (you can attempt to use a hacked PC to run OS X, but it's not without it's own issues).

Comment: And I think "Hackintosh" is also illegal, so... the cheapest entry is the Mac Mini I think (I might be wrong, not following it closely).

Comment: Not illegal, per se. Installing OS X on non-apple hardware is against the OS X' EULA. So its a violation of the license agreement, but that in and of itself is not illegal.

Answer (score 0):

With [Airplay SDK](http://www.airplaysdk.com/airplayforiphone.php), it is possible to use Visual Studio and C++ for iPhone development. It allows deployment to device on Windows. However to create properly signed apps for AppStore submission, OS X is required.

Since Airplay SDK is a multi-platform development environment focusing on games, it is not intended for applications using iPhone API's directly. So when using it, developer is actually writing Airplay application that just happens to work on iPhone too. For something like games using OpenGL ES written in C++ this is not a problem. But "productivity" applications using native iPhone UI components are out of question with Airplay SDK.