# iPhone development on PC

Tags: iphone, windows, ios-simulator

Can anybody shortly describe solutions to start develop for iPhone on PC?

Comment: Despite the snarky answers, I think this is a useful question.

Comment: Realize that a Mac is a kind of PC?

Comment: Realize that Mac owners like to distinguish themselves from owning 'just a PC'.

Comment: This has been asked several times before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine#28573 etc

Comment: Check out DragonFireSDK.  It allows you to use Windows to create apps by using C/C++ code.  www.dragonfiresdk.com

Answer (score 8):

You do not need necessarily a Mac. It depends on your requirements for the application.
What you can always do is creating a [**web application**](http://developer.apple.com/safari/) for the iPhone.

Here is a nice [tutorial with Aptana](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-iphone/) (Eclipse based IDE for web development). Aptana seems to have some kind of iPhone simulator integrated.

There are various toolkits available, e.g. [**iui**](http://code.google.com/p/iui/) and [**jQTouch**](http://jqtouch.com/), to simulate the Look&Feel of iPhone apps.

Answer (score 2):

Get a Mac or run OSX server under VMWare (install OSX86 on a separate partition)...

Answer (score 1):

Use an Open Source Toolchain normally used for jailbroken dev. It *should* work for the app store...

Answer (score 1):

Chris Hardy did a good session on using C# for development on an iPhone using Monotouch at the last DDD at Microsoft, Reading UK last month. His session was recorded. Heres a link to the video. http://vimeo.com/9150434

Answer (score 0):

There are some good discussions of iPhone development from a .net developers perspective here:

http://dotnetrocks.com/archives.aspx

Shows: 468 and 454, there is also an upcoming show on the 3rd of march

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm I haven't used it, but those that I have talked to say its good :) unfortunately it costs money :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial going through getting iBoot, VMWare installation, then using phonegap to develop with 1 code base and then compile to multiple platforms (including iphone and andriod).

http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/developing-for-the-iphone-and-ipad-by-runing-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-on-a-pc/