# iPhone application demo on Windows

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261267/iphone-development-on-pc)

I have developed an iOS native application. My manager wants to give the demo of that application on a Windows machine. Is that possible?

When I was searching, I found [MobiOne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development#Mobile_application_testing). But that is only to check HTML applications. Is there any iPhone simulator for Windows.

Comment: You just can't do it. I doubt you will ever be able to.

Comment: @woz.. I don't want to develop any iOS app in windows machine. I know that is not possible at all. My only question is, whether I can show my app demo on windows machine or not, as it was asked by my client? Also, do u have any idea on MonkeyTalk iOS agent?

Comment: Yes, I posted the second two links too hastily, but this is a duplicate of the first. You are asking how to run an app on a Windows simulator.

Comment: why not use real iPhone to do the demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share the Mac screen remotely with [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) and give demo on it. Simple.

Comment: This is probably the best possible solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jeremy1026.. I suggested this before but my client hasn't accepted it. He may give the demo at any time.. Thats the prob :(

Comment: there is a window iphone simulator available .. you need to install mono Android SDK for Visual Studio. some where you can put your app in simulator path location

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not such thing. There is, as you said, applications for HTML applications, but for native iPhone applications there are no such solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remotely login to your Mac and go from there is the best option.
2. Do ad-hoc distribution to your real iOS device and do the real demo there.
3. There is a thing called [Hackintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86) that allows you to install Mac OS X on your PC. You can also go from there if you really want to run it from your PC.

There isn't any iPhone emulator for Windows, as far as I know.