# Is there a way to develop an iPhone game on a PC?

Tags: iphone, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Basically, that's my doubt.

I want to develop an iPhone game on my free time, but I dont want to buy a Mac, so, is there a way to use my pc to develop the game?.

Thx in advance.

Comment: if you want to develop mobile apps without paying the apple tax, you should look into Android.

Comment: Or Windows Phone 7 even, though it's early days...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows is a similar question with some useful answers. Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine#28573

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
Apple does not allow development on PCs.

Comment: For more info go to : http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=537583

Comment: And... what about Hackingtosh?

Comment: That's prohibited by the EULA.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to develop a game using your PC using something like Unity but you will require a Mac to be able to deploy your application to an iPhone.

http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a PC to develop iPhone applications.

If you want to develop applications on Windows, you can setup the toolchain and use it. However, you will not be able to submit your applications to the App Store.
http://code.google.com/p/winchain/

You can also install OS X onto your PC, and run XCode/iOS SDK in that way. Since you have what is effectively a Mac, you can buy a iPhone Developer Program membership and submit official applications to Apple's App Store.

Comment: So, you are saying that if I buy a developer key from Apple I can fully develop an application?..

Didn't know that.

Comment: On Windows? no. 
On a PC running OS X? yes, of course.

Comment: I thought that was not possible to install/use SDK on hackingtosh.

Comment: Nope, it's definitely possible to do so. For all intents and purposes, a hackintosh is a Mac and it runs OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Your you can install Mac OS X in your PC, only for development, though I don't advise it you. Then, you can install xcode and create an account in iPhone Developer Center and to begin your bad experience with this.
But you'll have big problems of stability with Mac Os X in you pc.

The way more logic, buy an Apple, I recommend it to you.

Comment: Yes, Im gonna buy a Mac Mini.

They are not that expensive after all, I only need it to develop.. so, I dont care about video card, or tons of HD space, etc.

Comment: You can look at the previous mini Mac, since the new one though it is better has risen of price.
It is a good solution since the mini Mac is much better than a PC, and you can to start developing indeed.

Comment: Yes, I'll buy the "fat" minimac :)

Btw, can I start developing and testing my game without first paying to Apple?

Comment: This is completely false. PCs running Mac OS are not less stable than Macs running Mac OS.

Comment: Even if that's true, ppl says that is impossible to deploy a game using xCode on hackingtosh, so...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is an SDK for Windows that allows you to code in C/C++ and turn it into an iphone game, but you are limited to 2D games and you have to use their API.  Here's the link.

http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Rent a Mac remotely from [macincloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com). You can use your Windows remote access program to log on to their Mac server and you can start developing app on an actual Mac.