# Can I start building iOS apps using only iPad 2 and iPhone?

Tags: ios

I do not have a Mac so I was wondering if I can start building iOS apps using my iPad 2 and iPhone only?

Comment: Many questions of this kind here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273428/is-there-a-way-to-develop-an-iphone-game-on-a-pc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261267/iphone-development-on-pc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very short answer: No.

Xcode doesn't run on iOS.

Comment: +1 - I tried to answer just "No." but was rejected with the error "body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 3" d'oh

Comment: You can buy a using and cheap mac mini on ebay. Old models (Core 2 Duo minimum) runs Lion, and XCode 4, so there is no problem to build an application for iOS 5. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

if u want short answer, it's "**No**"

long answers:

1. there are some intresting apps on ipad2 for creating another app.... but only for play, totally not practical.
2. if u have a PC(windows or linux), u can run VMvare, install OSX. then u can install Xcode, and develop ios app.  Remember, Xcode is the key for apple platform developing.
3. Buy a Mac, if u want develop app more than a try.

read this for more info: [Starting iPhone app development in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

you can use third-party software, but in the end you always need to compile a XCode. Except if you use web solutions. Consider that still does not have the same user's native programming expirence.

Link to watch:

```
http://phonegap.com/
http://www.appcelerator.com
http://www.melablog.it/post/10228/creare-applicazioni-per-iphone-senza-conoscere-objective-c-e-cocoa-5-idee-per-tutte-le-necessita
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO
If remove your ONLY word in question, you can remote connect to Mac thru your iPad or iPhone

Answer (score 0):

You can, actually create installable web apps in iOS, using an html editing app like Koder, however do not expect to utilize hardware features like the camera or vibrator, since you are still a webpage running on a chrome less browser.  Anyways good luck building web apps!