# building iOS apps without a mac os?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)
>   [Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533847/alternatives-for-ios-development-under-windows)

hi there, any way to build iOS apps only with windows or linux?

i know there are some ways to get mac os started on a VM, but i mean only on win/linux.

i know there is some plattform like phonegap, but there you need a mac to build your apps too.
any other ways?

Comment: the problem is, i dont need a framework, because with the framework i'm not able to build ma .app package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some alternatives, but afaik there are no ways for pure obj-c/cocoa development. See here:

[Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533847/alternatives-for-ios-development-under-windows)