# Develop an iOS application in Windows 11

Tags: python, ios, windows, qt, mobile

I want to develop an [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) application using [PyQt 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt) and [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) in Windows, but I read that we need a Mac to do that. I have a [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)-based [Acer laptop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire). Is there a way to develop an app using these tools and be Windows-based?

Comment: This seems to be a mega duplicate. See e.g. *[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/)* (132 answers), *[iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/)*, and *[Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533847/)*

Comment: Do you have a source for *"we need a Mac to do that"*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need macOS to develop an iOS application.
You can develop it on Windows by using Mac [VMware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware).
So you can use macOS in VMware or VM Workstation.

Comment: This seems to be contradicted by *[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/)*.

Comment: Not really. The solutions in that question all involve using the Xcode toolchain n some way in a virtual machine running osx or cloud-based MAC services. You can, with some difficulty, run macOS on generic x86 hardware, but you can't decelop for iOS with windows only.