# Minimum requirements for iPhone development

Tags: iphone, macos

I think this is not best place to ask this question but ..i don't know about correct one..

I want to buy machine on which i make my development process but the mac systems are out of reach for me...i am planning to buy mac mini..
will that works for me?
if not then please tell me a good tutorials about making a hackintosh ....
i know that there are some tutorials on this topic  but maximum of them are demanding a huge hardware requirements...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190662/whats-the-cheapest-mac-development-box-possible - The accepted answer on this question uses a mac mini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you're developing web app or native apps for iPhone. If you're only planning to develop web app, your hardware requirement is lower. If instead you're planning to develop native app, a current Intel Mac Mini running 10.6 (or newer) is a good starting point. My suggestion is to invest in RAM rather than hard disk since you can always get an affordably-priCed external hard drive.

I wouldn't recommend a hackintosh unless you don't mind occasionally having to troubleshoot why things don't work when they're supposed to.

Please mark your question as answered if you're happy with the responses given. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a Mac Mini it will definitely work though you would need some DVI/VGI TV out for it.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a latest Mac Mini, or a MacBook. That will work pretty fine.

Answer (score 1):

mac mini is good enough for iphone development.. plus you'll need the developer license for device testing and publishing of course...

P.S. and yes this is not the right forum for this question... may be [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get a Mac to build a real iPhone or mac development..any way refer this [Mac on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 1):

Even a second-hand intel based Mac is enough... Basically all macs released after 2006.

But sure you'd want a new one, it's damn cheap and you'll get all the 64-bit goodness and everything else =)

Answer (score 0):

```
* Motherboard - Asus P5K-VM
* Video - GeForce 8800 GTS 320MB
* RAM - 4 GB of OCZ SLI (4x1gb in dual channel mode)
* CPU - Intel Core 2 Duo E6750
* HDD1 - Seagate Barracuda 250GB (vista)
* HDD2 - old Seagate Barracude 80GB (40GB for mac, 40GB for time machine)
* iAtkos 5i - this one is the best from what i had (ive tried kalyway and ideneb). U can use native Update with it.
```

OR

```
* Motherboard - Asus P5B-VM SE (i think, but SE for sure)
* Video - OnBoard (support for dx10)
* RAM - 2 GB of OCZ
* CPU - Intel Core 2 Duo E7400
* HDD1 - Seagate Barracuda 250GB (vista + mac)
* iAtkos 5i
```

Both comps are booting 10.5.6 with SDK 3.0

Comment: Don't you need SDK 4 to submit any apps now?

Comment: if you want to submit to the app store you'll need Snow leopard, aka 10.6