# Write iPhone app in Windows XP

Tags: iphone, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

How can I write and debug iPhone applications on windows XP?

Comment: you can't develop iphone apps on windows xp.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Android if you want to develop ([resource](http://p-xr.com)) on Win XP.
 Or go and develop in [Adobe Flex](http://www.adobe.com/nl/products/flex/flex_framework/) ( flash ).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is already on here. Your PC specs I think are low.

[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Best bet is to do HTML5, CSS3 and Ajax applications rather than xCode, Cocoa...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the apple FAQ states:

> Can I develop iOS applications on
>   Windows?
>
> No. iOS applications can be developed
>   only on Mac OS X.

See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/200-iOS_Development_FAQ/faq.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH12-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to develop iPhone apps on Windows.
Use [Mono Touch](http://monotouch.net/)

Its not any web based kit. It don't use HTML5 or Flex or CSS or Ajax.
You can start developing if you know C#.