# Do i have possibility to develop iphone application in WindowsOS(Win7)?

Tags: iphone, mobile, ios4, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

I am new to iphone applications.
My doubt is, can i develop i phone applications in windows platform by installing iphone SDK, emulators etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight and simple Answer = **No You can-not !**

Apple, wants confine its iphone ecosystem only to Mac OS. Its just that Windows is so prominent in the market so, they have to give away itunes for windows (For Consumers only)

But, they have such a good SDK and such a strong hold on iphone market that gives them enough confidence to keep the SDK and the emulator to Mac.

One possible work around :

> You can use Hackintosh ('Hacked Mac OS, to run on normal PC instead of a powerPC')

For more info, I found a related answer : [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)