# Iphone programming [TCP APP] + Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, sdk, tcp

i know that similar question are already asked some time but cant find anything that maches my  "problem"

just a quick and dirty:

is there a sdk where i can programm a TCP (sending/recieveing) tool for iphone with windows?

there are some article that telling it is possible to talk tcp with html5

If html5 is a good choice for this what i need to "start" programming for iphone.

before the flame wars start: im usually coding heavly with AutoIT for my Windows tools.

Comment: "Quick and dirty" isn't cutting it. Give us more detail of what you want to accomplish. Your question is really confusing as written.

Comment: sorry for confusing, i have a tool running on my server that communicate by tcp, i want to make a iphone app with i can send/receive tcp messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS is built on UNIX, you can use any C code or libraries that uses TCP sockets. Any examples you find using C and sockets will apply. You can also use Apple's `CFSocket` library for more high level access.

TCP sockets are TCP sockets, they can talk to anything (Windows included) if it's on the same network.

To write the software and install it to an iPhone, you will need a Mac. For more info see [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)