# Is this possible to code for iPhone if you use windows?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

I meen possibility to compile the project that could run at for example iPhone4 ?

Comment: I use virtual machine of mac, but it need more memory, does this what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do same thing. I did not find a way.

I don't like how apple is doing it, then I switched to Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this using Adobe CS5 which supports development for iOS. I have managed to create a working app using this. If you need extra info this might help:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html