# Developing for Iphone without XCode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)
>   [iOS development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595507/ios-development-on-windows)

I began to study objective-c and cocoa with a friend but there's a problem. I have a mac and i can write code and stuff on XCode, but my friend can't, because he have not a mac. Is there a way to download the iphone sdk and use objective C and Cocoa on a windows supported IDE? So he could write, test and send his code to me so i can try it on XCode.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Only if using OS X in a virtual machine and AFAIK that is illegal.

Comment: You can use VMWare to install macOS in pc, hackintosh etc but only for learning purpose. :p

Comment: I know but I think it is very slow.. I don't know what to do. I would like to work with my friend to develop apps, but i think it's impossible..

Comment: No its not very slow, but for installing and running xcode, u need 4gb ram at least for 10.6 and above...

Comment: Using 10.6 with a VM is prohibited by the EULA which explicitly states that it is for use on Apple computers only. The EULA for 10.7 is different but only allows you to use it in a VM if the host is already using it. So, either way it wouldn't be legal. If they don't care about the legality they can obviously do that but I wouldn't encourage it.

Comment: Yes that is why in my first comment I mentioned ** for learning purpose :p **

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's for learning purposes legally. You are prohibited from using it on a VM under any circumstances, unless there's some clause in there I'm unaware of.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer guys! I hope to solve this horrible situation as soon as i can!

Comment: @luca_music You're welcome. I hope you find a solution that works for you and you and your friend end up developing some great apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to find an IDE for Windows that supports iOS development using Objective-C and Cocoa Touch. Your best bet would be to run Lion using a VM (virtual machine). However, this is illegal to the best of my knowledge. Yes, since Lion there have been some changes to the EULA (End-user license agreement), but these only allow Lion to be run on VMs if the host machine is already running Lion. That's right: you can run Lion using a VM if you're already using it. Not very helpful. Some people would whip out the old "who's going to catch you?" stuff, but that's not exactly sound legal advice.

Your friend has a few (legal) options. They can buy the cheapest device capable of running Lion and the latest version of Xcode. Alternatively, or in the meantime, if you're only doing basic stuff, you could have them write out their code into any text editor which supports Objective-C syntax highlighting, such as [NotePad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/). Then, they can send the files to you and you can add them to a project in Xcode. Of course, this means you'd probably have to do most of the nontrivial debugging and all of the compiling, etc, and that might be harder on beginners who are more prone to make mistakes. There's really not much you can do. You could look into GNUStep but that's closer to Cocoa and not Cocoa Touch (you said Cocoa, but since you want to make iPhone apps you obviously mean Cocoa Touch, which is different).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bad answer, but you and your friend can share a sigle mac/or mac mini whatever you have, with TeamViewer. When you are not working allow him to access your mac through teamviewer.