# Develop for iPhone using Windows plateform?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows

can I develop an application for iphone using windows plateform?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: your answer is xamerin hybrid framework, but it will require mac machine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research or effort.

Comment: one simple option is to use the vmware (virtual machine)

Comment: You can try install [hackint0sh](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: You could develop on windows using VM but it would really slow and better option is to go for mac machine if you want to develop apple app or product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Apple the only way is to use a Mac :

> To develop with the iOS SDK and Xcode, you must have an Intel-based
>   Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or later and you must be registered
>   as an Apple Developer.

Check the answers here :

[iOS development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595507/ios-development-on-windows)

[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/ios-dev-center.html

Answer (score 0):

**Embarcadero - RAD Studio** supports developing applications for iPhone/iPad and is running on windows
(Formely known as **CodeGear / Borland** , which made **Delphi** / **Turbo Pascal** )

[http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Creating_a_FireMonkey_Mobile_Application_(iOS_and_Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Creating_a_FireMonkey_Mobile_Application_%28iOS_and_Android%29)

Though they use some internal tools for **iOS** libraries, you still will need a **VM** ( **virtual machine** ) for Mac emulation for advanced development.