# Developing for iOS on PC

Tags: ios, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

I would like to know if and how is it possible to (legally, read further) develop an application for iPhone/iPad using a PC rather than a Mac, only having to buy the physical mobile device for final testing and deployment.

**I know** that the illegal way is to obtain a pirated copy of Mac OSX and run it in VMWare (or install it on a PC), then getting XCode the same way and the only thing one needs to buy are the developer account and the physical iOS devices.

I wonder if there is a legal way too. Something that can run on Windows or Linux. Needing to buy a Mac increases both the budget needed for the project and the risk of not covering it by revenues.

Thank you.

Comment: please use search. This question has been asked many many times and the answer is still **NO**. The only ways to program for iOS(using Xcode) not on a Mac is VMWare or a Hackintosh.

Comment: You'll find your answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Needing to buy a Mac increases both the budget needed for the project and the risk of not covering it by revenues.

You can buy a secondhand Mac Mini or similar on eBay (or from other good secondhand websites, or perhaps your local computer shop) for a low amount of money. Same goes for iPhones and iPads, and anything else that you could possibly need.

As the other commenters have stated, it is not possible (and illegal in Apple's eyes) to try to run MacOSX/Xcode et al on a PC rather than on a Mac computer of sorts.

Hope this helps, best of luck with your project!

Comment: To upload an app to iTunes, you need a Mac.  However, you don't have to buy one . . . just use the virtual Macs hosted by http://www.macincloud.com.  It (currently) cost $8/day, $20/month and works on a PC.  

You will have to use the Mac's keychain, but you can still develop in Windows using Adobe Air with the new certificate, and upload to the virtual Mac using DropBox.  (You will also have to understand the Mac iTunes uploading process, which you can find in the Apple docs.)