# Is Windows-10-Qt-quick-QML code cross-compatible with IOS

Tags: qt

If I am developing an application using Qt quick QML on windows 10, can I deploy my project and test it on an ios device? I have read this post [Developing iOS app on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771361/developing-ios-app-on-windows) but it seems to be somewhat in conflict with what I have read. The chosen answer in that question says that you need a macOS to develop IOS applications. Qt's documentation and other posts have said that you can port applications onto various platforms with the same code "Code once, deploy everywhere". So will I be able to actively test my qt quick QML code on an ios device from a Windows 10 development platform?

Comment: The code runs anywhere, but you cannot cross-compile/deploy it anywhere. You can cross-compile for Windows perfectly fine, but not for iOS and also not for macOS. This is inherent to the Apple platforms, not to Qt.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, you can set up a "hackintosh" which can be in a VM. VMware Workstation can be patched to allow installation of macOS. You can probably also do this with VirtualBox. It's gonna be slow and sluggish due to lack of accelerated graphics drivers, but it works. You can run Qt Creator, Xcode and the iOS simulator in the VM.

Comment: Right so it would have to be a macOS absolutely. Luckily I work on a mac, everything qt was just on my windows partition. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You need either macOS computer or virtual machine with this system.