# How could I program Iphone app on window 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

I want to write an application for Iphone but I don't have a Mac machine. Ussually, I setup a Hackintos on my laptop to do this. Can we do this directly on window environment? which tools?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this directly from Windows.  Get a mac mini.

Answer (score 0):

By Apple's definition, this is impossible. They 'require' you to use a macintosh, however, you can install VMWare on your Windows machine to run Mac OSX. That should work, however I recommend you just buy a cheap Mac (used, maybe Mac Mini).