# How to install XCODE in windows 7 platform?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Can you tell me how to install Xcode in windows 7 .... Or there is any other way to develop Iphone app on windows 7 ???

Comment: There are numerous existing questions on this topic already. Have a look at, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

X-code is primarily made for OS-X or iPhone development on Mac systems. Versions for Windows are not available. However [this](http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.in/2010/12/installing-ios-sdk-and-xcode-on-windows.html) might help!

There is no way to get Xcode on Windows; however you can use a different SDK like [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/)  instead although it will not use Objective-C (I believe it uses Lua). I have however heard that it is horrible to use.

Source: [classroomm.com](http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?PHPSESSID=8j5b729rocc4cm8h7end7edvi6&topic=5088.msg13883#msg13883)

Comment: If you are a. C# developer then this liknk should help you.. http://xamarin.com/ios