# apps development on virtual machine

Tags: ios, macos, vmware

i have PC -Intel i5,dell inspiron 5520.and i have installed vmware & on that i have installed mac OS lion 10.7.

1. is developing apps on vmware is legal?
2. if it is legal,is it creates same machine code, which creates by original mac.
3. if it creates same machine code, then can we deploy successfully apps to app store.

Comment: It should not matter. Please look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Comment: Legal? Maybe, maybe not. Criminal? Maybe not. Contravening the user license? Yes, certainly.