# Create app for Apple with windows OS

Tags: ios, windows, macos

I have a computer with windows OS and i would create an app for AppleStore.
I must have a computer with apple's OS or can i program with windows?

Comment: There are plenty of resources to answer this question. Start [here](https://www.google.com/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214083/is-it-possible-to-develop-mac-osx-apps-on-windows).