# how to connect iphone4s to windows machine for iphone app development preview

Tags: iphone, ios, windows

I want to connect my iphone to my laptop ( windows ) for to iphone mobile app development.

is there any way by that i can create iphone application on window platform ?
if not then is there any way by that i can connect my iphone to my laptop and see the perview ?

Comment: There are already several similar questions on stackoverflow. It's not possible unless you install Mac OSX on your laptop (either as hackintosh or as a virtual machine)

Comment: my question is i have a iphone so is there any way that i can connect to it or work..ovarall wt i need for development is ios and that i have as a IPHONE

Comment: Why do not you make any research before asking question which already asked hundreds of times on this site. :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Comment: How the hell did this guy manage to get >1Krep

Comment: That remains *Mystery*!!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is using [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), which will let you develop iOS apps using C# on both Mac OS X and Windows platforms. Unfortunately is not free.