# React Native + Firebase + Expo versions love triangle issues

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to implement React Native authentication with Firebase using Expo. I am currently having following versions:

- Expo: 20.0.0
- npm: 5.4.0
- firebase: 4.3.0

I get the following error:

> Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.

#### How I got here

Expo recommends npm version 4.6.1. (In fact, on Expo forum [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/npm-install-is-breaking-my-apps/909) in post about  npm breaking apps, it has been advised to downgrade to 4.* version of npm). But firebase 4.3.0 fails to install with npm version 4.6.1. So I upgraded npm to latest 5.4.0. Firebase installed fine, but now I get above error in Expo. And here is error message from when I try to install firebase with npm 4.6.1:

[image]

#### Question(s)

- Can I use some older version of firebase which will work with npm 4.6.1? Which version would that be?
- Is there some other workaround (other then older firebase version)? Did anybody implement RN + Firebase + Expo successfully?

---

**Edit**: seeking answers on Expo forum: [link](https://forums.expo.io/t/npm-install-is-breaking-my-apps/909/17)

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase

Comment: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/full-native-firebase-integration

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
sudo npm install -s firebase@latest
```

it works for me