# Codename One upload to Apple Store

Tags: iphone, codenameone

I would like to upload an app to the Apple App Store and working myself through the process. I have already published to Google Play without any problem.

Following a Coursera video, I learned that you need a Mac to get the app into the store (because of the app loader), but since I don't have a Mac or an iPhone, I am looking for alternatives.

Googeling around I found a couple of solutions (virtual machine, cloud solutions) here at : [Build an iOS app without owning a mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739387/build-an-ios-app-without-owning-a-mac) . Is the list complete or are there any other ways? What would be the easiest solution?

Many thanks in advance for any king help.

Comment: As James said Mac In Cloud should work and should have a free quota. Notice you don't need to "build" from a Mac! When you build an itunes IPA it should work fine for submitting. You only need the "Application Loader" tool from a mac which you can use to select and upload your Appstore IPA. To use it in the map just click the magnifying glass on the top right and type in "Application Loader".

Comment: Shai, many thanks for your kind answer. Just one doubt: you say: "To use it in the map ...". What map would that be? Is this part of the mac upload interface?

Comment: I think he meant Mac. Just use the search tool to find the application loader app on the Mac. You can also use Google Drive or Dropbox to transfer your app file.

Comment: Yes mistyped Mac ;-)

Comment: I almost figured :-) ... thanks, as always, for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet is probably something like MacInCloud, where you rent time on a Mac that you remotely log into from your PC. It worked great for me until I got a Mac for other reasons. It’s not very expensive.

Comment: If all you ever do is upload to the app store, MacInCloud is hard to beat, but if you ever need to do your own xcode builds and real debugging, you can get a used mac pretty cheap.