# how to run Xcode projects on Windows?

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, macos

I am running xCode projects on mac in my office ,but i want to work at home too, i surfed a lot But only heard one way to run mac on windows is by using VM , is there any other hack or way to run properly on windows .

if it is can only happen through VM does ios SDK works properly on VM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been looking for this as well when I started iOS app development. In short, if you value your time, I advise you to give up (or buy a MacMini / MacBook). Especially if you need to stay compatible with what you do at work.

There's ways, they say, but getting there is complicated, depends on your hardware and also requires you get hold of (illegal) modified iOS images.

This is all being complicated even more by Apple requiring you to always stay in the front (higher iOS versions require higher XCode versions require higher OS versions require better hardware). This on itself is costly overtime but if you're taking the unsupported 'Windows' route it means that even if you succeed, you may end up in a deadlock after some time after all.