# iOS in windows machine

Tags: ios, windows

I want to learn iOS, but unfortunately I do have only windows machine.
The tutorial I am watching is based on mac operating system.
Is there any way to practice or run  iOS simulator in my windows pc. If yes then
how to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Comment: no you cant run ios simulator on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible if you set your mind to it. But the simple answer is no. Xcode will not run in Windows and nor will the iOS Simulator. There are other projects out there that offer iOS Dev from a Windows based machine. For example:

http://phonegap.com

Also ManicDev has a blog entry on this subject: 
http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available

**Bottom line though: If you're serious about developing for iOS - get a Mac. Life will be much easier. Promise. :)**

Comment: While you can install Phonegap on a windows machine you still need a mac to test anything you build as you still need to either use the iOS Simulator or use an iPhone via xCode. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Agreed. I was just showing the OP that it's easier to just get a Mac. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple iOS simulator only works on OS X..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like macincloud.com they give you access to a Mac server with the xcode tools installed. It can be a good way to start without making the huge investment.

You could also try Xamarin Studio which also you to use C# to build Android and iOS apps. Could be worth a look.