# iOS 7 app development on windows

Tags: ios, iphone, windows

I am pretty new to app development, so I have a pretty basic question. I currently use windows, but have an iphone 5s. I have read that you can write and compile objective-c on windows, but will have problems when trying to run and test the app through the iOS environment. My question is can I develop/write/compile objective-c with windows, and then test/run the application through iOS on my iphone? Is this method possible? Or would it be best to use a mac mini with my windows environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 0):

NO window can't install xcode compatible. but you install virtual mac on your system and then work ios app. Else you need to buy mini mac it will very compatible for you.