# Is it possible to develope for iOS/Android on windows and then "Export code to mac OS"?

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I want to develope for iOS and Android using Cocos2d-x or Unity 3d. From what I've heard, you will need a computer running mac OS to legally get your app in the app store. The problem is that apple computers are horribly overpriced and I'm on a budget so I can't afford to get a mac. I want a computer that is fast and the only mac that fits my requirements is the Imac, which costs around $1500 dollars and I can't afford that, considering I'm only 14. I could build a better computer than that for only $700, not to mention I could upgrade it later down the rode.

What my question is, is if it's possible for me to develope on a windows computer using Cocos2d-x or Unity 3d, and then transfer my code to a mac mini (maybe like a cheap used one that costs like $400) and then will i be able to legally put my app on the app store? I haven't worked with a game engine before so I don't know if this is possible or not. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to export for mac OS with unity, however, your code cant be the exact same.Also i would consider buying a mac mini and making the game version for mac there, because it will provide you with better tools and Mac OS are anyway better for programming.

Comment: Thank you for answering I'll probably buy a Mac mini then thanks