# Need to develop iphone App on Windows Development Meachine

Tags: ios, windows, xcode

This might be repeated question, but i am not able understand those answers or it old post?

I am having a windows meachine, how to develop a iphone app and test that in simulator?

Is there any **IDE** or tools which can be install/work in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, you need a machine with OSX in order to compile Objective-C, so unless you run a virtual machine or install OSX in your computer, you can't.

You can create an App using Appcelerator, Xamarin, etc, but it won't be native Objective-C.

Find a more extended answer here:

[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine?rq=1)