# Run command on the development Mac from iPhone

Tags: ios

Does Apple provide a way for an iOS app (running on a connected iPhone or the simulator) to execute a shell command on the host Mac? This is to help with development/debugging. I want to be able to tap a button in the app and have it run a script on the Mac.

I have a working solution that involves running a server on the Mac and having the iPhone talk to it but was wondering if there's another approach provided by Apple. UIAutomation's [UIAHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/UIAHost/UIAHost.html) looked relevant but I want to run the command without Instruments.

Comment: Someone which 4k+ reputation should understand and know the question type we accept and do not accept in this community.

Comment: I added some more details to the question but I think it's totally reasonable even if there are several approaches. Tons of helpful questions are open-ended e.g. looking at related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are running under the debugger you can use a symbolic breakpoint to execute a shell script.

In your view controller, create an `IBAction` handler for your button. It can be empty.  Wire it up to your button as you would normally.

Then, in the Breakpoint Navigator in Xcode, add a new Symbolic breakpoint.  Set the symbol to `- [MyClass myButtonHandler]` and set the action to execute a shell script and set the checkbox to automatically continue after the breakpoint.