# How to develop iOS applications, if I can't afford a Mac?

Tags: ios, macos, windows-7, virtualbox

I'm learning, how to create mobile applications. The Android part is ok, I can test it well. But to learn, and test for iOS, I have to install iOS simulator, which works only on OSX. But I can't afford to buy one. Here in eastern europe the used ones are also really expensive.

I tried to install OSX (Hackintosh) to a virtual machine. But it doesn't really works, because my laptop has an old AMD processor.

Is there any way, to write and test iOS application on Windows7? I am very desperate now. I see no chanche to write an iOS application. Everywhere I ask it, people just respond: "buy a mac". If you close my question, please help, where should I ask it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody has asked this before:  [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

If you have a fast Internet connection, this might work too: [http://www.macincloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com/) Or, if you want to spend some money but not too much: [Mac Mini from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=Mac%20mini&_armrs=1&_from=R6&_ipg=)

Comment: One Mac Mini from eBay costs as much, as a monthly salary in my country.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. The second option only costs $20 a month and an Internet connection. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the macincloud service may be good for me. I write the code on windows, and connect to the cloud only when I test. There is a 1$/hour payment option.

Comment: @Iter Ator That's smart. Just make sure you don't end up wasting too much time to debug codes you've written for hours without testing. It can cost you more than $20 if you write everything at once and expect it to compile at first attempt

Answer (score 2):

This answer has already been in the rounds, but i'll say it once more, if you've got a PC with minimum core i5 and 4GB RAM, you can run OSX Mavericks on VMWare (comfortably with XCode 6, iPhone 5s Emulator and Safari all running at once). There is a good detailed tutorial on Youtube which works 100%. (I can't give you the links as it suggests illegal way of procuring the OSX Mavericks image)