# do we have to pay for the ios sdk or we can install it on zero cost

Tags: ios

I want to know if ios sdk is free or there is any charge on it. I want to download ios sdk in my windows 8 with no cost.Is there any way? I want to use this sdk for creating app on phonegap.
I have searched many times but I'm not getting perfect information whether ios sdk is free or not.

Comment: The SDK is free, but you can't install it on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Comment: three downvotes? I know this question is fairy easy and can search on internet. But from newbie viewpoint, this is not so obvious so they come to here and ask. I think there is no problem with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS SDK is free.  It is part of Xcode, which is a free application available through the OS X App Store.  Xcode does not run on Windows, it requires a computer running OS X.  See: [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

A developer subscription is $99/year, and allows you to publish applications on the App Store, as well as deploy them to your own devices for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The *iOS SDK* is free. You just download [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/). This will include SDK and IDE for developing native ios app.

There aren't any ways to develop an ios app (native apps or cross platform apps) without having MacOS (so if you don't have a mac computer, you can [install](http://www.hackintosh.com/) mac os on your pc, if you wish).

Nevertheless, some frameworks (such as PhoneGap, Xamarin ...) supports developing apps on Windows/Linux machine, but at final step, compile your source code into binary file, you still need XCode (and XCode is only run on MacOS). So, you can use those frameworks, build, run and test on other windows-support platforms such as Windows Phone, Android. At final, you can borrow other mac computer for testing on ios. This will minimize time you have to work with mac.

Last but not least, for publishing ios app on Apple Store, you need $99/year subscription to register [ios Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/). This contrast to Android and Windows Phone platform, just $25 and lifetime, you don't need to register for second times.

Hope this help :)