# Is it possible to work with xamarin with visual studio without any help from mac?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I would like to work in xamarin with visual studio in windows without any help from mac and apple because gona work in .net. what are all the requirements do i need to install in windows? how cal i start at first? i have visual studio 2010 and also VS2012 version myself.

Comment: You can as long long as you only build apps for Android and Windows  devices.  Requirements are available in the online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

Xamarin has made it loud and clear.

If you break the rules, you are fully on your own, like the previous discussion revealed,

[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)