# Xamarin: Why do I need a mac to compile the .ipa file when developing for IOS?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, ipa

I'm just curious. With android all I need are the correct SDK packages and a slow-to-boot emulator.

I understand that I do need a mac, I would just like to know why? And why I can't use a VM?

Comment: It's just a case of keeping everything tied to your platform. If you want to develop for iOS Apple would love you to buy some shiny gear instead of running it on a VM. It's just business

Comment: The WHY is that the build tools provided by Apple (which Xamarin uses) only run on OS X.  And Apple's license does not allow OS X to be run in a VM on non-Apple hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it on a VM. If the legal part for you is not really important you can install Mac OS X on your normal PC. Just google a bit for Hackintosh.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)
There are detailed information about developing iOS apps with windows and so on

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link, I'll be sure to check it out. :)