# Can I launch my libgdx app on IOS device with Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, libgdx

I am using Android Studio on windows and do not own a MacBook. 
I have "ios launcher" project generated by libgdx, can I launch it?
And if you can, would it require jailbreak to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct way: no, you need a Mac to build. But here's a related question to yours that may help you to workaround:
[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine?rq=1)

And to avoid such unpleasant situations for your next projects with libGDX, you can check wiki about creating projects: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29

A related quote from wiki:

> To additionally target iOS:
> - A Mac, iOS Development does not work on
>   Windows/Linux thanks to Apple. 
> - The latest XCode, which you can get
>   from the Mac OS X App Store for free. 
> - RoboVM, simply install the
>   Eclipse plugin. Make sure to update the plugin frequently!