# Developing and/or designing iOS apps on Windows

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

After developing an app for Android we want to step forward a bit and do it for iOS. We have no prior experience with developing for iOS(the code is not the problem, but the tehnique is). With a bit of research, i found that you need Apple Computers or VM's or Apple Mirroring for this job, because it is "imposible" to develop in Xcode(meaning that i try to keep it as native as i can). I also found Xamarin and other tools but finaly decided with my team upon a Mirrored Mac ( inCloud). The problem is that, with little financial backup we do not afford to buy a Mac or to Buy more than 1 subscription(30-35$ for a month is a lot for starters). Now i want to know if there is a safe way to work for iOS on Windows(maybe without installing anotherOS on PC), or at least to Design( visual)- storyboards, views and others..for the app.. Maybe one can work on the Cloud Machine and the others can work from their home computers..and than kind of merge the projects.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try building a [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com).

Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine) post on this question.

"Now i want to know if there is a safe way to work for iOS on Windows(maybe without installing anotherOS on PC)" 
Short Answer, no!