# iOS app development phonegap or xamarin on windows

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, appcelerator, phonegap-build

I really dont get it. I see I can develop Iphone Apps with

xcode (objective-c / swing)
xamarin
phonegap
titanium appcelerator
....

But do I need a Mac even with phonegap etc. or is it possible to develop on windows with those Frameworks?

Comment: Might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Comment: so you can  do all the work on windows but at the end you need a mac to sign ?

Comment: Yeah, somewhere in build chain must be a Mac. Apple requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely develop iOS in Mac using Xamarin with the help of [Xamarin Live Player](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/xamarin-live-player-almost-takes-the-mac-out-of-ios-development/).

You can debug,develop and deploy without any help of mac but to sign and release the app you will still need a Apple system

Answer (score 0):

You need an actual iOS device to fully develop and test all of the app's device features before submitting to the App Store. More [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide).