# Writing ios application on windows

Tags: ios, windows, macos, visual-studio, virtual-machine

I always wanted to make an app for ios device. I don't have Apple OS device but I have a VM. How can I use it to write apps on Windows.

I do not want to write code in VM. I want to write it in for ex. Visual Studio, send it for compile to VM and debug in Windows.

Is there a way to do so without Xamarin. (Cuz it doesn't work on VM for some reason)

Comment: Objective-C with iPhone SDK is only available for OS X, you can ofcourse write all you code in notepad, but you wil not be able to compile it. For compiling you will need a Mac with OS X, you can use a VM but this is not allowed by the end user agrement of OS X.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)