# Is it possible to create IOS app and put it appstore if I have windows 7?

Tags: ios, windows, virtualbox

I want to create app for my website,I heard that IOS app development time is less than Android thats why I want to create android app.But I have not Mac,I want to learn swift and create IOS app.Is it possible on windows?(I heard that if I use virtual box to use mac it will be illegal thats why I think they will not allow me to put my app to appstore,is not it)?

Comment: "I heard that IOS app development time is less than Android thats why I want to create android app"—this sentence makes no sense

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine

Answer (score 0):

App development time is not necessarily faster for iOS than it is on Android. It all depends on what kind of app you're building, your skill level, and many other factors.

Developing iOS apps on Windows is possible but not recommended unless you really know what you're doing. I'd suggest you try building an Android app, or look into one of the many cross-platform options, like PhoneGap or Xamarin.

Comment: What about if I create app on PhoneGap will I able to put my app to Appstore from Windows 7?