# Unable to install Xcode 8.1 on my Windows 10 computer

Tags: xcode, windows-10

I've been trying to download Xcode but when I open it nothing happens.

Xcode_8.1.xip

Do I need to us using a Mac to be programming for iOS? I am currently using Windows 10.

Comment: This is such a poor question. A simple search anywhere would uncover the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, yes, you need to have a Mac, or some other macOS running computer to run Xcode. But...

There is a way to run Xcode on Windows, however it's a bit of work. You can follow a tutorial on the internet like [this one](https://www.alltechbuzz.net/install-xcode-on-windows-for-ios-sdk/) to get Xcode working on Windows.

Let it be known that even though Xcode will run on Windows using this, it is definitely not good in quality compared to on a Mac, as there will be lag and unnecessary difficulties that wouldn't be there on Mac.

Comment: Any other recommendations to get swift working on windows or do I need to do this?

Comment: @Michael There really isn't a proper solution to this. This looks to be the only way for now...