# How do I code in Objective C on windows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, windows, ide

I want to create apps for iOS. I make games in C++ and SFML, so I decided to use Objective C after further research. I can't find any windows IDE's, so I came here. What am I supposed to code in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score 4):

You can install macOS on a virtual machine like virtual box or VMware.

Here is a tutorial to install the virtual machine: [tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox)

Comment: Note that this is violating Apple's EULA. It is prohibited to run macOS (virtualized or not) on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: i agree with you, but for test application you will found no probleme

Answer (score 2):

Yeah unfortunately the only way to create iOS apps is through MacOS. You'll have to get your hands on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I supposed to code in?

The short answer is "Mac OS." Some people build a "hackintosh" (A PC running Mac OS) and build their iOS apps on that, but that is a violation of Apple's copyrights and developer agreements.

You can also run Mac OS as a virtual OS, but with the same legal issues.

Answer (score 2):

I hav tried to work with a virtual machine on linux and it was not easy to set-up. Ultimately, an iSO development project can take hundreds of hours of coding time, and you will rely a lot on the stability of your system. So why starting from an inperfect arragment?
The cheap way to start is to buy an Apple mini. It's cheap and it will get you started. You can move to faster Mac later on when you are sure you are committed to finish the project.

Comment: sneaky idea to get apple mini

Answer (score 0):

You can try Xamarin. Now belongs to Microsoft and I believe it’s part of Visual Studio. It should be able to export projects for both iOS and Android. But I haven’t used it myself, so I can’t confirm for sure.