# Developing for iOS device in Windows environment with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform

I'm new to Flutter, was just wondering if it's possible.

I've tried building the demo code using intellij with given instruction (https://flutter.io/setup/). It runs well on android device, but can't find the option to compile and run on my iOS device.

Comment: In order to compile/run for iOS you'll need a Mac. This requirement has always been the case since the first iPhone.

Comment: @MorrisonChang is correct. You probably cannot run the iOS version from a Windows machine.

Comment: With NativeScript it is possible to build the iOS version in the cloud (https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/getting-started/build). With Xamarin you can use the Xamarin Live Player app to test your code on an iOS device. I hope Google will also come up with something similar in the future.

Comment: unfortunately flutter not capable for it.
flutter looks good but with adobe air you are able to build and run application on ios device via usb without needing a macos. adobe has it ages ago ) Google should also able to make that support.

Answer (score 120):

You can do your main development on Linux or Windows with Android Studio or Visual Studio Code. Then use git to move the code to macOS to test it with Xcode on an iOS simulator/device and deploy it to the App Store.

You could do all development on macOS but you can't do all development on Linux or Windows. I'm not too pleased with Apple for making overpriced machines and then forcing us to buy them. Since I can't afford a fast Apple computer, I am planning to do most of my development on Linux and then just do testing and deployment on my painfully slow Mac Mini.

**Update**

It seems like there are more possibilities now. Read the following articles:

- [How to develop and distribute iOS apps without Mac with Flutter & Codemagic](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-develop-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/)
- [How to sign Flutter apps for iOS automatically without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-sign-flutter-apps-for-ios-automatically-without-a-mac-a2dc9cfa5a6c)
- [Developing and debugging Flutter apps for iOS without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)

Personally, I ended up buying a MacBook Pro for way too much money. I have to admit that it is convenient, but I have done very little up to this point that really required it. I'm doing all of my learning and development in Android Studio and usually use the Android emulator. Every now and then I fire up the iOS simulator, but I haven't been required to.

My advice is to keep using your current system (Windows or Linux) for as long as you are learning and even while you are developing your first Flutter apps. Eventually you may appreciate the convenience of having the iOS Simulator and Xcode on the same machine, but there is certainly no rush.

Comment: There are also some hosted virtual macs available. I am using a cloud hosted one and it works great for compiling. Another alternative would be a virtual machine on your computer.

Comment: @Bostrot Any link(s) for hosted macs would be helpful.

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria I personally only know macincloud but a google search will get you more.

Comment: can anyone recommend a tutorial on how to set up virtual machine with mac OS on Windows?

Answer (score 39):

You could do that with a Mac (or Hackintosh, or VM), but since we don’t have access to a macOS machine we can use one remotely via **Codemagic** or **Travis CI** — completely **free**! (as long as your project is on a GitHub, Bitbucket or GitLab repository).

First, create an account or sign in to [codemagic.io](http://codemagic.io).

Then, click the settings (gear) icon next to your app. Scroll down and click on “Build”. Make sure Mode is set to Debug, and select iOS under Build for platforms.

After that, build the app (**Start your first build**).

Codemagic will send you an **.app** file via email. Rename it so that it ends with .zip. Extract it, and you’ll get a folder called Runner.app. Create a folder called Payload and place Runner.app there. Finally , compress the folder called Payload — this will be your IPA file (you may rename it to **.ipa**).

Alternative: Building the app with [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/)
You’ll need to create an account on Travis CI and let it access your GitHub account.

Then, create .travis.yml on the root of your project with the following contents:

```
 os: osx 
    language: generic 
    before_script: 
     - brew update 
     - brew install --HEAD usbmuxd 
     - brew unlink usbmuxd 
     - brew link usbmuxd 
     - brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice 
     - brew install ideviceinstaller 
     - brew install ios-deploy 
     - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b beta --depth 1 
    script: 
     - flutter/bin/flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign
    cache: 
      directories: 
      - $HOME/.pub-cache
    before_deploy: 
      - pushd build/ios/iphoneos 
      - mkdir Payload 
      - cd Payload 
      - ln -s ../Runner.app 
      - cd .. 
      - zip -r app.ipa Payload 
      - popd
```

[More info](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)

Comment: yeah, but I would like to run it on iOS and take a look at the new version at least once before rolling out. You can't just test on Android, then build for iOS prod

Comment: @KirillKarmazin I recommend you to write tests based on OS and use Fastlane or Codemagic CI/CD before build and release. 
In other scenarios that you mentioned, you had to build Flutter in Mac then your target release first would be iOS than Android.

Comment: Does my Bitbucket repository must be public in order to be accepted for free builds on CodeMagic?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves no, it doesn't require to be public

Comment: free but limited by the number of hours, compiling using macos VM is also expensive on codemagic / github actions

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you use a virtual machine to do your thing.. I had a Mojave MacOS installed on my Windows 10 and I had things running smoothly!

A Mojave image can be got from https://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/mac-os-mojave-10-14-1-vmware-image-free-download/

I found this useful as I had some things that I wanted out of the Mac world while I had a dell latitude.

Comment: were you able to connect your iPhone device to your mac os on virtual machine?

Comment: I didnt test that out.. but i dont think if it is possible... a simulator might do the work

Comment: @emanuel_sanga I can confirm that it is possible. I did it without any problems. I've set up a VMware Workstation virtual machine on my Windows 8.1 and run a Mojave image there. Then you have to install XCode and do all the Apple ID related sign-in steps. Then you can plug in your iPhone (signed in with your Apple ID) and they work fine. By the way - real physical device seems to be the only way to test notifications since they don't work properly on simulators (for example if you are using Firebase)

Comment: Note that it's against MacOS terms of use to install on non-apple hardware.

Comment: Yes yes @Inrego. But from quora, seems to have effect when done for mass & commercial production. Here's the link https://www.quora.com/Is-it-illegal-to-install-OS-X-on-non-Apple-hardware-aka-Hackintosh. 

I would be glad if you also share your resources for others to see too

Answer (score 9):

3 years later after the this question was asked:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/announcing-amazon-ec2-mac-instances-for-macos/

AWS now supports one demand macOS as an EC2 instance.
Haven't tested this out myself as this was just released, but hopefully, this can replace the painful little mac mini that's working extra hard without work-life balance XD

Answer (score 6):

Apple has made compiling of iOS applications exclusively avaible to macOS.

You can read through [this answer and thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573/6509751) to look into workarounds for getting it to work on Windows.

Basically there is **no** other **way for *Flutter***, but [*Xamarin*](https://techcrunch.com/2017/05/11/microsoft-now-lets-ios-developers-deploy-run-and-test-their-apps-directly-from-windows/) and [*NativeScript*](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-with-nativescript-sidekick) provide support for it.

Answer (score 4):

you can read [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)

it uses some tools and [CodeMagic](https://codemagic.io) to build Flutter app for Ios.

1. put your app on GitHub (public) and give access to [codemagic](https://codemagic.io)
2. then you should build your app using code magic for IOS.
3. then you should use Cydia Impactor for signing the file that
   CodeMagic has sent to you
4. prepare your windows machine by installing libimobiledevice ,
   ideviceinstaller,which.
5. Modify Flutter code to not looking for Xcode
6. Running and debugging

I have used this method it works fine you can hot reload and debug your app the downside is you have to enter apple id password in Cydia Impactor which for sure you should use a second apple id and after apple provisioning profile expiring you should sign your code with Cydia Impactor again. but it's so much cheaper than by a Mac or rent one.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently, this method doesn't work. There are some records on the Cydia Impactor forum which haven't been answered since December 2019 regarding 71 error message that does not let install the app. Also, they ask for your iCloud login and password.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you can also use a utility tool named Odevio to :

- Configure XCode
- Test your app on the iOS simulator
- Build an IPA for on device testing
- Sign and publish your app

First you need to install the Odevio through the website: https://www.odevio.com

Secondly, set up Odevio with your Apple Developer Account : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

Thirdly, in the case you want to build and publish your app for testing and/or for publication, you can select the corresponding build type and create one.

And that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

Now we have Xcode Cloud https://developer.apple.com/xcode-cloud/ so hopefully we will see some decoupling from iOS. If we would have iOS simulator on Windows that would put the crown on Windows iOS development.