# Can I use Flutter to develop IOS in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter

- Question 1. Can I develop for IOS using flutter only in Android Studio without Xcode on Max OS?
- Question 2. If 'Question 1' is possible, is there a limit to the functionality?

I do not think it will work on windows OS.
When the operating system is Mac OS, is it possible to develop both IOS and Android?

Comment: You would still need MacOS to build app for iOS, since it seems to rely on the XCode command line tools to build

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194084/8954451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing for iOS device in windows environment with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes**, You can develop Flutter apps (both iOS and android) on Android studio which is available for Windows, Linux and macOS, but to distribute iOS apps (created using Flutter), you would need Xcode (which is only available for macOS).

However, if you are on macOS, you can develop and distribute Flutter apps for both iOS and Android.

You can configure any IDE for your Flutter development (see this https://flutter.io/using-ide/) and to release/distribute apps for each platform, you can fall back to Xcode and Android studio.

See more info here: https://flutter.io/setup-macos/

Answer (score 11):

You can develop the app completely on Windows or any other operating system. All you need is an IDE or editor (Android Studio or VS Code).

**But to compile/release the app for iOS or for tests on the iPhone simulator, you will need a Mac with XCode installed.**

The good thing is that the code you've written in Dart will (normally) work on iOS without any changes, so you can just develop on Windows (and test your app on Android), then ask a friend who owns a Mac if you can borrow it for a day to compile it for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other users, it's more than possible to completely build your app for use on all platforms with Windows, however Apple has opted to restrict iOS compilation to Apple devices only - you'll have to use a VM, a Remote Computer or a physical Apple computer if you'd like to compile your app for iOS