# Debug flutter on iphone using VS Code on windows 10

Tags: iphone, dart, windows-10, flutter

Is it possible to emulate a Flutter app in debug mode on an iphone connected to a windows 10 machine using VS Code? it all sounds like it wont work when I type it out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing for iOS device in Windows environment with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need Xcode installed for that and that runs only on OSX.