# Flutter Apple iPhone cannot detect in my Windows laptop

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, vs-community-edition

I am using Windows for the flutter development.

I have physical iPhone device when I connect that to laptop, laptop can detect it. But in Visual Studio Code or in Android Studio, it is showing "no device is connected".

This is first time I am connecting iOS to my Windows 8.1 laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing for iOS device in Windows environment with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter)

Comment: Develop on android emulator instead

Comment: I have low end laptop. If i use emulator than laptop performance will decrease.

Comment: Whether there is any option to connect physical ios device instead of emulator