# Issue while Build and install ios app using flutter and codemagic on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ios, ubuntu, flutter, codemagic

I tried to build flutter ios app using Codemagic and install with Cydia Impactor. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
The link is what I refered to.

==> [Developing and debugging Flutter apps for iOS without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)

Codemagic built flutter app successfully and returned Runner.app file. I made .ipa file from Runner.app and then installed on ios device using Cydia Impactor tool.
The problem is that when run the app it exit immediately and display nothing.

This is my hello world flutter example code for build ios  app.

```
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is run by Android emulator well. What cause the app exit on ios device?
I wonder how to debug app on my environment. Plz help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include all code inline and appropriately formatted, That will help the community assist you. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter/55773996