# Does flutter support ios or iphones on android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I know this may sound stupid,but i was searching for a very long time on how can i make an IOS app without using x code or having a mac OS,and i finally find this plugin on android studio called flutter,but my question is can i connect an external iPhone (NOT AN EMULATOR) and start the app on that iPhone from android studio?

I have tried connecting my iPhone to my PC using USB,but it doesn't show up in android studio.

And it doesn't show me any error like your iPhone isn't supported etc..

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact No.
Apple doesn't support the idea and you have to consider using Mac os and xcode, for which you can use e.g. a virtual machine.