# Flutter build failed for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have built in flutter, and published an app for the google play store. Now i have gotten an apple developer account wanting to publish it there too. Since i do not have a MacBook i opted to build it using Codemagic. It's a cool tool. I put my code on GitHub and everything seemed to work fine. But after around 20 minutes or so of codemagic building i get this error.

```
== Building for iOS ==

== /usr/local/bin/flutter build ios --release --no-codesign ==
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.truth.tab for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                            306.3s (!)
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           1487.2s
Built /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.

ERROR! Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!
Building with Xcode 11.3.1 (11C505)
== xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -config Release archive COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO ==

❌  error: Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')




Build failed :|
Running xcodebuild failed
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I can't be the only one who's gotten it. I am using Android Studio and Flutter to develop this app.

Comment: In order to ios for your physical iphone or for release you need a developer account. So buy an apple developer account and inside ios module add it in flutter target

Comment: @JawadAhmed I already have a developer account and i don't understand what you mean by "add it in flutter target"

Comment: okay so in the flutter project you have an ios folder. Open this in Xcode.

Comment: @JawadAhmed the issue im having is that i do not own a MacBook. Is there a way to add what i need to add in just the file? I have it open in Android Studio on my Windows machine.

Comment: Okay, follow these step.
1) Install VMware
2) Install macOS in it.
3) Install Xcode in it

Comment: Thank you. I will do that and get back when i got it

Comment: sure .if it helped you upvote it

Comment: @TedBoman check out this answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194084/6804642 
You can deploy on your windows environment itself.

Comment: @JawadAhmed I got VMware up and running but when I try to build the app in Android Studio it fails and in Xcode it's stuck on the launch screen. I made a different question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356249/flutter-app-for-ios-crash-on-startup-with-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that Codemagic does not have the `.mobileprovision` file(s) and signing certificate to use when signing your iOS app.

There are two ways to solve this.

1. Generate your `.p12` and `.mobileprovision` files using a mac (keychain access) and your apple developer portal.

   > (If you don't have a mac, this is not a possibility)
2. Give Codemagic access to your apple developer account so they can generate/have access to the files they need.

   > This process is very easy with codemagic. Here is a link to their documentation: https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing/ios-code-signing/#automatic-code-signing