# Flutter app for iOS crash on startup with Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I have done research for for so long and have not yet found a solution for my issue. I am building an app for iOS using flutter and I moved the app from my windows machine to a virtual macOS. Now when I try to rum the app on the Iphone simulator (Iphone 11 pro Max), the app crashes on startup with this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           190,5s
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Configuring the default Firebase app...
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    "currentDataServiceDescriptorChanged:",
    "carrierBundleChange:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:"
)
    "currentDataServiceDescriptorChanged:",
    "carrierBundleChange:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:"
)
    "currentDataServiceDescriptorChanged:",
    "carrierBundleChange:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:"
)
    "currentDataServiceDescriptorChanged:",
    "carrierBundleChange:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:"
)
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c70e49 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Runner                              0x000000010c8aadc6 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedAnalyticsCorrectly + 409
    4   Runner                              0x000000010c85dbc0 GADEnvironmentIsSupported + 4134
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5223e848 _<…>
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? I have added the GoogleService-Info.plist ursinne the add file in Xcode so now I don't know what's wrong. I hope anyone can help me and ill be so grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project and now it works.