# Why am I getting "Failed to build for iOS" while building code in codemagic for Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I followed the steps as per the post in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55773996/13761601 using codemagic.io but while building the app in am getting the "Failed to build for iOS" error. I don't understand why am I getting this.I have attached the screenshot below as well .Please have a look.Also the screenshot of the logs as well is attached

Any other answers which gives ways to build and test IOS apps on windows easily would be easily welcomed as well

[image: screenshot of failed to build for iOS error]

[image: logs screenshot]

Logs output:

```
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
```

Building instagram.photo.video.downloader.repost.insta for device (ios)...
Project base configurations detected, removing.
Running pod install...                                              7.0s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A admob_flutter
  A firebase_analytics_web
  A firebase_messaging
  A flutter_inappwebview
  A flutter_local_notifications
  A path_provider_linux
  A shared_preferences_linux
  A url_launcher_linux
  R firebase_admob
  R flutter_native_admob
  - Flutter
  - android_intent
  - device_apps
  - firebase_analytics
  - firebase_core
  - firebase_core_web
  - firebase_in_app_messaging
  - firebase_remote_config
  - flutter_webview_plugin
  - fluttertoast
  - intent
  - open_file
  - path_provider
  - path_provider_macos
  - permission_handler
  - share
  - shared_preferences
  - shared_preferences_macos
  - shared_preferences_web
  - sqflite
  - url_launcher
  - url_launcher_macos
  - url_launcher_web
  - video_player
  - video_player_web
  - wc_flutter_share
  - webview_flutter

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `admob_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/admob_flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `android_intent` from `.symlinks/plugins/android_intent/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `device_apps` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_apps/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_in_app_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_in_app_messaging/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_remote_config` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_remote_config/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_inappwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_inappwebview/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_local_notifications` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_webview_plugin` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_webview_plugin/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `intent` from `.symlinks/plugins/intent/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `open_file` from `.symlinks/plugins/open_file/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_linux` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_linux/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_macos/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `permission_handler` from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `share` from `.symlinks/plugins/share/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_linux` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_linux/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_macos/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_linux` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_linux/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_macos/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_player_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `wc_flutter_share` from `.symlinks/plugins/wc_flutter_share/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: CocoaPods-version.yml, save ETag: "871dbc3ac66ab065476ee696d0c77eeb-ssl"

CocoaPods 1.10.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.10.0.beta.1

  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt, save ETag: "dc581eeab599c36e921b2f682f0981b3-ssl-df"
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.5/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.5/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.7/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.7/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.9/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.9/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.12/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.12/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.11/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.11/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.2/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.2/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.5/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.5/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.3/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.3/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.2/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.2/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.2/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.2/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.3/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.3/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.3/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.3/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.3/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.3/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.11.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.11.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.2/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.2/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.7/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.7/Firebase.podspec.json
      ..
..
..
...rb:308:in `tap'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/builder/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Error running pod install

Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS

Comment: This is a question for the support channel on their Slack. Please be sure to answer your own question here so the answer can be found by others in the future. Here's a link to their Slack. 
https://join.slack.com/t/codemagicio/shared_invite/zt-9h8qkpfa-RlLIF1Bmh867~0pRwqzMtA

Comment: @scottstoll2017  Thanks I will ask there

Comment: the link is no longer active

Answer (score 2):

Try running `pod repo update` in the post-clone script to see whether that works out for you.